# Android: Do something when app is resumed

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I am writing an android app with multiple activities. The app needs to check-in with a server when the app is 'resumed' (be it fresh start, from locked screen or switching from a different app etc.). In other words, same stuff needs to go into onResume() of all activities.

The check-in involves launch of an AsyncTask and prompting for username/password etc. if the check-in fails.

I have things working by keeping identical onResume() method on each activity (i.e. check-in code is replicated in all activities). Surely there is a better way to do this. What is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your use case. If all your activities require the same functionality, you can create a base activity. All your activities will extend it. Move this logic into base activity's `onResume()` and then all your activities will have this logic.

If that approach doesn't work, you can try moving this logic into a separate controller class, and then use it in all activities that need it. This is a bit more flexible and will help you to avoid code duplication.

Comment: So simple!!. Sorry I don't have enough reputation to upvote.

Comment: That's great :) If you think we answered your question, please accept the answer that you think is the best. Thank you.

Comment: @RamanKrishnan upvote is not necessary. Accepting the answer is.

Answer (score 2):

you can create a base activity e.g.:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    /* your code here*/
}

}
```

All your Activities should inherit from BaseActivity like:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {
/* your code */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to check in all your activities `onResume()` you can define a BaseActivity and extend all your activities from this and in `onResume` of your Base activity you can do your stuff.

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     @Override
     protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // do your stuff here
     }
}
```

But if you need to do your stuff when only your app resumes things may get a bit more complicated. There's not a direct method which gets called when your app resumes.

So you can create a custom component callback in your `Application` class like below:

```
public class CustomComponentCallback implements ComponentCallbacks2 {

      @Override
      public void onTrimMemory(int level) {
         if (level == ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN) {
            isAppWillResume = true;
         }
      }

      @Override
      public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onLowMemory() {

      }
   }
```

And create a custom activity life cycle callback like below:

```
private static final class CustomLifecycleCallbacks implements ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
    @Override
    public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
        if(isAppWillResume){
           // do your staff
           isAppWillResume = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {

    }
    //...
}
```

Define a static boolean field in your Application class like below: register your callbacks.

```
private static boolean isAppWillResume = true;
```

And in `onCreate` of your Application register your custom callbacks:

```
registerComponentCallbacks(new CustomComponentCallback());
registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new CustomLifeCycleCallbacks());
```

I'm not sure if this's the best practice to detect if the app is resumed but this solution works for me.

Edit: By the way if you don't want to extend all your activities with a BaseActivity you can only register a custom callback which i written about and in onResume you can do what you want. It'll get called when **any of your activity is resumed.**

Good Luck!